# Computing powers of diagonal + rank-1 matrix?

Tags: linear-algebra, rootfinding

I'm using a numeric root-finder to find $k$ satisfying $\|A^k x\|=c$ where $A$ is a symmetric $d\times d$ diagonal + rank-1 matrix. How to compute $A^k x$ efficiently?

- For integer $k$, I can get the answer in $O(k d)$ time using iterated products.
- For general $k$, can use dense eigendecomposition of $A$ in $O(d^3)$ time
- Is there a way to do it faster than $O(d^3)$ for general $k$?

My $d\approx 10000$, $k\in(1,10000)$

Answer (score 8, accepted):

[This paper](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0024379515005406) shows an algorithm to compute the eigendecomposition of symmetric diagonal-plus-rank-1 matrices in $O(d^2)$.

Comment: Interesting that they don't reuse work between eigenvectors, procedure is called $d$ times independently.

Comment: Found some Matlab code from a different paper as  dpr1eig.m in https://zenodo.org/record/7338121#.Y_eoEezMK0p

Comment: I posted this question on mathematica.SO where Henrik Schumacher gave an [explanation](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/280669/217) of approaches and an [implementation](https://github.com/HenrikSchumacher/DPR1Eigensystem) of Stor's [paper](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0024379515005406).

Comment: By coincidence, I encountered this paper that pursues the eigendecomposition of a unitary plus rank-1 matrix in O(n) space / O(n^2) time. I don't think this captures the OP's use case, but I leave it here in the hope a future reader might find it useful: Aurentz, Jared L., et al. "Fast and backward stable computation of roots of polynomials." SIAM Journal on Matrix Analysis and Applications 36.3 (2015): 942-973.