# Approximating eigenvalues of DPR1 matrix with special properties

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues

In my application, I have a sum of diagonal $A$ and rank-1 $B$

$$T=\underbrace{\text{diag}(1-2\alpha h+2\alpha^2 h^2)}_A + \underbrace{\alpha^2 hh^T}_B$$

Where $h$ is a vector $\in \mathbb{R}^d$ with positive entries decaying faster than $1/i$, $\alpha>0$ and $\|T\|<1$.
Can eigenvalues of $T$ be approximated faster than $O(d^2)$?

Earlier [answer](https://scicomp.stackexchange.com/questions/42518/computing-powers-of-diagonal-rank-1-matrix) pointed to $O(d^2)$ algorithms for finding full eigendecomposition for general DPR1 matrix, but I'm wondering if the specific structure is useful here.

Motivation: this matrix describes evolution of errors of SGD with step-size $\alpha$ when used to solve Ordinary-Least Squares problem with Hessian $\text{diag}(h)$ and normally distributed observations. In contrast to standard gradient descent where error evolves as $\text{diag}(1-2\alpha h+\alpha^2 h^2)$

Comment: Largest eigenvalue can be obtained numerically using power method or algebraically using Tauberian theorem on the generating function of $\operatorname{Tr}(T^k)$ derived [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4654692/998)