# Powers of convergent DPR1 matrices in $O(d)$ time?

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-solver, iterative-method

Suppose $u$,$v$ are vectors and $A$ is a convergent $d\times d$ diagonal + rank-1 matrix.

How do I estimate $u^T A^k v$ in $O(d)$ time?

Powers of convergent diagonal $D$ can be computed in $O(d)$ time by [utilizing](https://www.wolframcloud.com/obj/yaroslavvb/nn-linear/forum-laplace-transform.nb) Laplace transform.
For a general DPR1 matrix, there's $O(d^2)$ [algorithm](https://scicomp.stackexchange.com/a/42519/18786) but I need something that works much faster.

Answer (score 3):

It is not necessary to compute $A^k$ in your case. You can do a matrix-vector product with $A=D+pq^T$ in about $5d$ operations, and so multiplying with $A^k$ via
$$
  A^k v = A (A (A \cdots (Av)))
$$
is going to cost you $5kd$ operations. The last dot product, $u^T A^k v$ is going to add $2d$ operations to that, for a total of $(5k+2)d$.

Assuming $k\ll d$, this is likely optimal. If $k\gtrsim d$, then you're already in the $O(d^2)$ case and the Laplace transform case is probably going to win.

Comment: Yes I'm looking at k>>d, but wasn't clear how to generalize the Laplace approach to dpr1 case.

Comment: I see, tough. Can you compute the eigenvectors of $A$ in better than $O(d^2)$? If so, you can expand $u,v$ in terms of these eigenvectors, and go from there.

Comment: It seems you can get a [single eigenvector](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/280669/217) in O(d), but full eigendecomposition needs d^2